# How to correctly Read Contacts information

Tags: android

I have been attempting to Read Contacts and just for the moment Log them to the console but I am getting a RunTime Exception error on my app. I have been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4_1UOFNLEY&t=1s

I am not sure if this is the correct way of getting contact details and would appreciate any advice. My end goal would be to eventually have a contact picker where a user can choose a contact and add their name to a list

I have the permissions working correctly (as cleared up by another user in another thread) but still having problems.

Method called in onCreate:

```
private void viewContacts(){

        // TODO CONTACT INFO - will log to console
        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        // to gets all contacs
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            // Access specific field of contact
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            //get phone numbers
            Cursor phoneCursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{ contactId }, null);

            Log.i("MY INFO", contactId + " = " +contactName);
            //get phone num
            while(phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
                String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                Log.i("MY INFO", phoneNumber);
            }
            // get email details
            Cursor emailCursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",new String[]{ contactId}, null);

            while(emailCursor.moveToNext()){
                String contactEmail = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                Log.i("MY INFO", contactEmail);

            }
        }
```

Error

```
/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{AppName.EditPlayersActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                                                                           Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
                                                                              at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
                                                                              at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                                                                              at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                                                                              at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:142)
                                                                              at AppName.EditPlayersActivity.viewContacts(EditPlayersActivity.java:175)
                                                                              at AppName.EditPlayersActivity.permissionsCheck(EditPlayersActivity.java:222)
                                                                              at AppName.EditPlayersActivity.onCreate(EditPlayersActivity.java:132)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687) 
04-24 17:37:48.206 19943-19943/AppName.squad E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: AppName.squad, PID: 19943
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{AppName.squad/AppName.squad.EditPlayersActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                                                                        Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
                                                                           at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
                                                                           at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                                                                           at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                                                                           at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:142)
                                                                           at AppName.squad.EditPlayersActivity.viewContacts(EditPlayersActivity.java:175)
                                                                           at AppName.squad.EditPlayersActivity.permissionsCheck(EditPlayersActivity.java:222)
                                                                           at AppName.squad.EditPlayersActivity.onCreate(EditPlayersActivity.java:132)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: don't forget to `close()` your cursors

Comment: I put my cursor.close(); after the main while loop and emailCursor.close() / phoneCursor.close(); after their respective While loops but I am seeing this error: 

"Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed."

Am I placing them in the wrong place?

Comment: i can't tell... i would have to see all your code to see what the problem is

Comment: i noticed that you get the `_ID` column as a string, but you should get it as a long: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID i suggest you to try to make your code as precise as you can

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided:

```java
Cursor emailCursor =
    resolver.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
        new String[]{contactId},
        null);
```

it seems that you are querying for email in the phone content provider. Shouldn't you use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI` instead?

Comment: This did not work, I got a new error this time. A SQL exception

Comment: could you post that exception?